# How do I make a textarea work in an iframe cross-browser?

Tags: html, iframe, cross-browser, textarea

I'm using the following code and the textarea appears, but I can't edit the text in the textarea or even get a blinking cursor to show in Firefox:

```
<iframe contentEditable='true'; src="you.php"></iframe>
```

"you.php" is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<textarea contentEditable='true';>the text.</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why use contenteditable attribute for textarea?

Comment: I would remove that semi-colon there.

Comment: Was just trying anything I could think of to make it work.

Comment: have you tried just a plain textarea without attributes or with normal attributes? Yea you also might wanna remove that semicolon

Comment: just use this `<textarea rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>` and don't use `contenteditable` attribute on your `iframe` too

Comment: The semicolon probably won't do any harm, but it is invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need contentEditable to edit the contents of a textarea. Try this:

```
<iframe src="you.php"></iframe>
```

you.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<textarea>the text.</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```